# Export to csv - Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a class in linq that query db table like this, and the question is: 
How do I export that data to csv? I have tried link suggested and I am using linq2csv and still want to know how to get column by their order? thanks!

```
var usr = from usr in db.User 
select new { usr.UserName, usr.Dept, usr.Name)
MainListView.DataSource = usr; 
MainListView.DataBind();

CsvFileDescription outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
                {
                    SeparatorChar = ',',
                    FirstLineHasColumnNames = true,
                    FileCultureName = "en-US"
                };

                CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
               string finalPath = mypath + "usr_" + DateTime.Now.ToString  ( "yyyyMMddhhmmssfff" ) + ".csv";
                cc.Write( usr, finalPath, outputFileDescription );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to control the sort order you must define a class with attributes like

```
public class User
{
    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 1)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 2)]
    public string Dept { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you change your linq query to use this class, eg

```
string mypath = @".\";  

var usr = (from u in db.User select new User 
               { 
                   UserName = u.UserName, 
                   Dept     = u.Dept    ,  
                   Name     = u.Name 
               }
          );

CsvFileDescription outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = ',',
        FirstLineHasColumnNames = true,
        FileCultureName = "en-US"
    };

CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
string finalPath = mypath + "usr_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff" ) + ".csv";
cc.Write( usr, finalPath, outputFileDescription );
```

Comment: I tried that, but I have date and time field that won't accept it. I have it in the class defined as dateTime and in the sql is date  and time too. Any ideas. Best regards

Comment: If the sql column allows nulls then you might need to use DateTime? instead of DateTime. If that doesn't help, then what error do you get?

Comment: it is datetime on both. Also the error is: DateTaken = u.DateTaken <--- connot implicity convert from datetime to datetime. thanks

Comment: I search and that ? is for nullable. so for my datetime I added: ----------> [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 4)] public string DateTime? { get; set; } <------------- same works for bool type thanks Sgmoore

Comment: If you have any nulls in your sql column, then this will be mapped to a c# null, but you can't set a normal DateTime to null, so you need a Nullable<DateTime> structure  (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx for more details). DateTime? is just a shorthand for Nullable<DateTime>. The same issue can arise with most other Sql types such as bit, money etc.

Comment: Thanks sgmoore Again! that helped

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already familiar with LINQ, I've used Matt Perdeck's LINQ2CSV ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library ) before and it's made my life a lot easier.

Comment: I am looking to have a button where the user press on it, then it prompt for save file to their computer. Also is there an easier way to do this. thanks

Comment: I have used that Linq2csv and used it this way (as updated on the first post). But I get the output to csv but column order is random. any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: Do you mean the order of the actual columns "UserName", "Dept", "Name" come out in random orders (sometimes "Name" then "UserName" then "Dept") or that the actual data ROWS are random? (not alphabetic?).  You probably just need to add a `.OrderBy()` to your linq expression.

Comment: there is an orderby already and that works fine. but the problem is: the columns not the rows. they should be: username, dept, name. but they are not. Any ideas! thanks

Comment: LinqToCSV sorts the properties using the attributes, which causes problems with anonymous types which don't have any attributes. If you want you can download the source code and amend it to bypass the sort. The section you need to amend is in the FieldMapper.cs file and AnalyzeType method and you need to skip the Array.Sort(m_IndexToInfo) line. The way I did it was to check the index value of each item in the array and if they are all set to the default value of Int32.MaxValue, then I skipped the sort line.

Comment: Can you please illustrate with code for 2 columns or so of how to use just the current code to put them in a list. thanks in advance

Comment: LINQtoCSV doesn't preserve your column order unless you use the [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 1)] attribute on all your properties.  But who wants to do that.  I would use ServiceStack.Text library.  It preserves column orders by default.  Works like this:  string csv = ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv<MyObject>(exportData);
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, csv);

Answer (score 1):

LINQtoCSV doesn't preserve your column order unless you use the [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 1)] attribute on all your properties.  But who wants to do that?  I would use ServiceStack.Text library.  It preserves column orders by default.  Works like this:

string csv = ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv<>(exportData);