# LinqToCSV returning Wrong Column Order

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

I am using LinqToCSV to create a CSV that is emailed to a user. The file seems to generate fine, except for when I open the file; the columns are not in the exact order that I specified in my Linq query:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.IO.TextWriter txt = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);

CsvFileDescription outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
{
    SeparatorChar = ',',
    FirstLineHasColumnNames = true,
    FileCultureName = "en-US"
};


CsvContext csv = new CsvContext();

csv.Write(childOrders, txt, outputFileDescription);
txt.Flush();

ms.Position = 0;
```

Comment: I don't see any linq query.Please provide your query, and provide what  did you get and what do you expect

Comment: Found My Answer Here!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303980/export-to-csv-linq-query?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Go to your object "childOrders" and on above your property add the attribute

```
[CsvColumn(Name = "ColumnName", FieldIndex = 1)]
public string ColumnName {get;set;}

[CsvColumn(Name = "ColumnName2", FieldIndex = 2)]
public string ColumnName2 {get;set;}
```